# How to use Javascript in a SharePoint 2013 App to receive messages from Azure Service Bus

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 App written in Visual Studio 2013 using Javascript with some Typescript that is hosted in App Catalog for the SharePoint environment.

The App contacts a REST service that puts a large amount of information (sometimes more than the 200kb limit of WebProxy) in JSON format onto an Azure Service Bus queue hosted on\in the Azure Portal.

In the callback for the function that contacts the web service, I need to be able to receive the message from the Azure Service Bus queue so that I can then display the information on the screen in the App page.

I've tried a couple of Javascript SDKs which don't seem to work reporting failure probably because of the cross domain.

I've also looked at NodeJs but there doesn't seem to be a step by step guide on how to set up an existing SharePoint App with NodeJs and then contact the Azure Service Bus with NodeJs.

I've also looked at the azure.d.ts (the DefinitelyTyped Typescript file) but that didn't seem to have the corresponding JavaScript or library for that file or for the node.d.ts. This means that when the App is running the error shown was that the functions in the azure.d.ts and node.d.ts were undefined. I think this was probably the right way to do it but I'm missing the Javascript file\library I need to include in my HTML.

Can anyone point me to a resource or give me some idea of how get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate Azure Service Bus in Node.js requires the node.js runtime environment, which seems that sharepoint hasn't provided.

If you want to integrate Azure Service Bus, you can leverage [Azure Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started/) or [API Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app/) or [Function Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference-node/) to implement the functionalities, expose APIs to your sharepoint's javascript scripts, and configure the CORS settings on your Azure App Service for your sharepoint endpoint.